# Prevent SQL 2008 R2 from increasing the version number

Tags: sql-server-2008

Apparently, whenever I attach a database in SQL Server 2008 R2, it has [the database physical version number increased to 660](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/SQL-Server-2008-R2-bumps-the-database-version.aspx). Is there anything I can do to prevent this behaviour?

I have to share database files with SQL Server 2008 ("plain") users and our webserver has also not yet been upgraded to R2.

I accidentally got R2 on my machine without noticing during install and I don't feel much like uninstalling R2, re-installing 2008 and then re-attaching all my databases (which would be impossible anyway, so I'd have to script them, cross my fingers and hoping nothing goes wrong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you *accidentally* get a new version of SQL Server on your machine?

There isn't a way to do what you're asking.  This is by design.  You also won't be able to attach those DBs created with R2 in prior versions of SQL Server...yes, even 2008 non R2.

Comment: I downloaded R2 from MSDN instead of 2008. I didn't notice the difference at the time. That sucks, I had hoped there was a registry key or something.

Comment: Hey, you can't *accidentally* install a new software version. You really *should* know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you replaced all the system and user databases with 2008 versions, you would still have an incompatibility between those and your executables.
Uninstall/ Reinstall of SQL and either revert to your old backups (you do have backups dont you?!) or use scripts and bulk load data out in to new (ensure you script out and bulk out before uninstalling first!)